# CONSTANTS in SQL Queries

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql

I am new to programming. and am using CONSTANTS in SQL queries
like this

```
private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";

final String query = "SELECT "+COLUMN_NAME+" FROM "+TABLE_USERS;
```

Is this a good practice?

Comment: What advantages and disadvantages do you think this approach has?

Comment: Allways use the [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: I think best practices are to use stored procedures or to use an ORM, this is neither.  For what reason are you going this direction?  Is there a specific reason?  You haven't given much information.

Comment: @Kayaman : most of the tutorial doing like this. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html . even the official documentation. I think the database modification can be easy.

Comment: I find it useless. Are you really going to change the name of your table? if so, changing the name in the constant will not be enough, you'll need a complete migration script. Same goes for column. My advice would be to never actually write SQL yourself (see how many questions on SO are about a missing space or colon in a CREATE statement), but use a third-party library for that.

Comment: @KevinEsche no preparedstatement in android

Comment: @njzk2 : Ok thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Such questions have been the greatest challenge ever I faced.
If you mean SQLite, Yes it is good to prevent query string errors in big projects.

Consider that you have more than one table:

```
private static final String TABLE_ROLLS= "rolls";
private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
private static final String COLUMN_USERS_ID = "id";
private static final String COLUMN_USERS_NAME = "name";
private static final String COLUMN_ROLLS_ID = "id";

final String query = "SELECT "+COLUMN_USERS_NAME+" FROM "+TABLE_USERS;
```

Hope be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is considered good practice, because if the database structure changes you will hopefully just have to change the constants in your class.

You tagged this post as both Java and PHP, but either way you should look into using query builder libraries.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I'm sure this had the PHP tag before I answered it.  If not, ignore the references to specific libraries.

=============================================

It depends on the pattern you are using and what limitations you are facing, the version of PHP being the main one.

If you are developing a stand alone application that is unlikely to change much, then using constants for table names only serves well if you expect to change the table names.

If you are developing a re-distributable application, then dynamic table names (on installation) is useful, see WordPress for an example.

If you are using an ORM like Doctrine2, then the table names are largely irrelevant, because they are abstracted away for the most part and you are working with classes.

Ultimately though, concatenating strings for SQL gets messy, which is why it is advisable to use a query builder which makes the use of constants easier to work with.

For example, if you are using PHP5.3+, you can using Doctrine DBAL.  You don't need to include an ORM to use DBAL, because the ORM of Doctrine uses "it", not the other way around.  If you are familiar with Doctrine2 ORM, you will recognise that the query builder uses class names, but that is the ORM magic converting them to their real table names.

In short, I would recommend using library that supports query builders which allows you to write queries into logical procedures without the need for concatenation.  Once you have this, there is nothing wrong with using constants besides potentially doing it for the wrong reasons.

Comment: plus one for noting `concatenating strings for SQL gets messy...`